# Working with SQLite in codeigniter

Tags: sqlite, codeigniter

I'm trying to get started with sqlite in the latest version of CodeIgniter.

My database.php looks like this:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db ['default'] ['hostname'] ='';
$db ['default'] ['username'] ='';
$db ['default'] ['password'] ='';
$db ['default'] ['database'] = APPPATH. 'db / producers.sqlite';
$db ['default'] ['dbdriver'] = 'sqlite';
$db ['default'] ['dbprefix'] ='';
$db ['default'] ['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db ['default'] ['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db ['default'] ['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db ['default'] ['cachedir'] ='';
$db ['default'] ['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db ['default'] ['dbcollat​​'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db ['default'] ['swap_pre'] ='';
$db ['default'] ['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db ['default'] ['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

I have created my table is produced and put data into it.

I'm trying to collect data with this code:

```
$query = $ this-> db-> get ('Producers');


foreach ($ query-> result () as $ row)
{
echo $ row-> name;
}
```

This gives me the following error: `Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in / Applications / MAMP / htdocs / webites / api / public_html / system / database / DB_driver.php on line 1183`

Or this error sometimes:

```
A Database error occurred

Error Number: 1

SQL logic error or missing database

SELECT * FROM (Producers)

Filename: / Applications / MAMP / htdocs / webites / api / public_html / controllers / welcome.php

Line Number: 23
```

How do I resolve it? I can not add data to either, there are similar errors

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue when using CI 2.1.0 and found the following fix for the fatal error:

In system/database/DB_driver.php change:

**Line 1165**

```
$message = $error;
```

to

```
$message[] = $error;
```

**Line 1169**

```
$message = ( ! is_array($error)) ? array(str_replace('%s', $swap, $LANG->line($error))) : $error;
```

to

```
$message[] = ( ! is_array($error)) ? array(str_replace('%s', $swap, $LANG->line($error))) : $error;
```

[Source](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/204478/)

Answer (score 1):

Never tried to use SQLite with CI, but I found a possible answer to your problem. Try adding 'sqlite:' in front of your database name, like:

```
$db ['default'] ['database'] = 'sqlite:'.APPPATH.'db / producers.sqlite';
```

[Source](http://blog.trevorbramble.com/past/2009/9/20/codeigniter_sqlite3/).

Comment: $db['default']['database'] = 'sqlite:' . APPPATH . 'db/producers.sqlite'; gives me error: FEL: SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file

Comment: don't forget `$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'pdo';`

Answer (score 1):

To solve the error *"Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings"*

I modify file in *DB_driver.php:1171*

adding this line:

```
$message = (array)$message;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in 2.1.0 preventing it from working with SQLite databases. You need to have updated version of CodeIgniter 2.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

try codeigniter 3x

```
$db['default'] = array(
        'dsn' => '',
        'hostname' => 'sqlite:' . APPPATH . 'db/database.db',
        'username' => '',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => '',
        'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
        'dbprefix' => '',
        'pconnect' => FALSE,
        'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
        'cache_on' => FALSE,
        'cachedir' => '',
        'char_set' => 'utf8',
        'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swap_pre' => '',
        'encrypt' => FALSE,
        'compress' => FALSE,
        'stricton' => FALSE,
        'failover' => array(),
        'save_queries' => TRUE
    );
```